# Is “X is learning very like Y” grammatical in English, and if it is not, then why?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs, parts-of-speech

*Like* can be used as an adverb. I have seen that *very* can modify adverbs in another post (it just can’t modify verbs). Yet this sentence feels odd. Why?

Why would the addition of *much* make the sentence sound better?

Comment: You’re leaving so much out that it’s hard to tell what it’s intended to mean. Do you mean something along the lines of *John is learning the craft very like the way his great-grandfather first learned it so long ago* here, or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: What do X and Y represent? Are they people? Subjects? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Use *just like* not *very like* here, and add in the missing verb after Y.

---

You have a good ear. I have two suggestions for you, and the first is that probably it would sound better if you used ***just like*** instead of ***very like***, although this isn’t strictly necessary. It just seems to sound better that way to me. I don’t know why.

Now if it were me making the call as to what’s what, I probably would **not** call this use of *like* an adverb, even though it undeniably does have some adverbial properties.  But even if so, it is here taking a complement, which isn’t so common with modifiers like adverbs and adjectives. Not unknown, just not common.

This may be why that for the most part, “adverbial” uses of *like* that take complements are these days much more typically analysed as a preposition, at least when that complement happens to be a noun phrase. For example,

1. You’re talking like Blackbeard.
2. You’re talking like a pirate.
3. You’re talking like him.

I think that’s the sort of thing you’re doing in your sentence, in that someone is learning like someone else **is** or **was** learning, or **did** learn, or **had** learned.

If you insert *very* before *like* in any of those first three examples, it sounds a bit short, but not ungrammatical. You’re right that it does seem to “sound better” with *very much*, at least to me. So your ear is telling you the same thing mine is.

It would probably sound even better still if you added back in some tensed verb afterwards. Why? Because that way you don’t leave so much out of the picture for people to fill in on their own. Plus you can choose the tense and aspect of the second verb separately from that of the first one so nobody has to guess.

When the complement to *like* is not a noun phrase but an entire clause, then it has historically been considered a conjunction (although some recent analyses even classify those uses as prepositional ones). For example:

4. You’re talking like he talks.  (or: *like he does*)

However, historically **some** people have been known to fuss mightily at that sort of use, preferring never to use *like* as a conjunction no matter what, which leads to them using *as* instead:

5. You’re talking **as** he does.

or even with a noun phrase so it can be a preposition again:

6. You’re talking like **the way** he does.

I’m not saying their complaint is legitimate. It is not. But it still happens, so if you would rather avoid getting scolded by people who like to scold others’ language, you might dodge it by keeping *like* as a preposition and *as* as a conjunction. I think they’re silly, but I also understand not wanting to be needlessly harangued. Up to you, really.

I personally think your sentence would sound better if you had a verb after your *like*. That’s why in a comment I asked whether you meant something along the lines of:

7. John is learning the craft very like the way his great-grandfather first learned it so long ago.

You can shorten that up using some tensed form of *to do* as a pro-verb here:

8. John is learning his craft very like how his great-grandfather once **did**.

But if that’s too “heavy” for you, instead of using *very* as an intensifier, try using *just* instead:

9. John is learning the craft **just like** his great-grandfather.

For my part, I still prefer for there to be some verb afterwards:

10. John was learning the craft **just like** his great-grandfather **had**.

It’s certainly not ungrammatical without that extra verb at the end, but doing it that way sounds better to me. I can’t say for sure why I feel this way.

Comment: An important skill to cultivate is to make up example sentences that are good examples of what you're trying to look at, **and** aren't full of irrelevant stuff that's not what you want to talk about. "X" and "Y" are not good words to use in examples. Simple sentences, if possible. But complete sentences, so that some context can be figured out.